# Pooled time series models and HAC residuals

Tags: time-series, panel-data, pooling

A canonical text for panel data models is Wooldridge's *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data*. His book is devoted to econometric issues such as endogeneity, unobserved effects, instrumental variables, and so on. To me, it's very striking that wrt this class of models he never discusses controlling for classic "Box-Jenkins"-type issues such as autocorrelation, trend, stationarity, unit roots, cointegration, etc, nor is he concerned with creating HAC residuals, at least based on the index to the 1st edition. Presumably, these core statistical issues for modeling time series are assumed away as not important enough to discuss.

However and in all fairness, multivariate tests such as a Ljung-Box test for autocorrelation or an "augmented Dickey-Fuller" for panel data don't exist or have yet to be developed, at least to the best of my knowledge.

So, have papers been written, have tests and protocols been developed that are appropriate for panel data and that address controlling for statistical issues such as HAC residuals? Cointegration? And so on?

Comment: If I were you, I would use *panel data* in place of *time series [models]* in the title.

Comment: @RichardHardy  I'm sure you're making an important distinction but it's not apparent to me. If panel data structures underlie pooled time series models, why can't the terms be used interchangeably?

Comment: I am no expert in these matters, but I think *panel data* is more standard and recognizable and hence practical to have in a title (especially if you say the terms are interchangeable). Of course, this is just an opinion.

Comment: @RichardHardy By "interchangeable," I don't mean synonymous. I think I understand your point but it isn't compelling enough to make me want to change the verbiage. Actually, I like using both terms as they cover more ground than would be if the topic was more narrowly (precisely?) stipulated.

Comment: In econometrics panel data means that we have pooled time series and we assume that the all the time series have something in common, i.e. the model for all the time series is basically the same. So the terms are not interchangeable. If you search for the terms in scholar.google.com, *panel data* has about 4 times as much hits as *pooled time series*, and quick perusal of the titles suggests that the first term is more used in economics and the second appears also in sociology, medicine. So the terminology is important in this case.

Comment: @mpiktas, Do you have an opinion on which of the two terms suits better in this case?

Comment: @mpiktas  "panel data means that we have pooled time series and we assume that the all the time series have something in common, i.e. the model for all the time series is basically the same..."  This is exactly the point of my question wrt panel data models, this assumptions that all the models "are the same." What are the tests that will *confirm* this assumption?

Comment: @DJohnson, Regarding your last comment, you may (1a) estimate an unrestricted model allowing for different behaviour of the different time series, (1b) estimate a restricted model forcing common behaviour, and (2) test whether the restrictions hold using a likelihood ratio test. Or use alternative Wald or LM tests that require estimating only one of the two models.

Comment: @mpitkas  I agree that terminology can be important. It's interesting to me that you use "panel data" and "pooled time series" in the same sentence. Is it a contradiction to declare them not to be interchangeable? Also, don't your examples from google scholar -- both the number of citations and cross-discipline usage -- suggest that you are applying a too restrictive definition by not allowing them to have "interchangeability?" To me, it's apparent that they are interchangeable, based on your evidence.

Comment: @DJohnson For me they are not interchangeable, because I can see a clear distinction in statistical methodology used in panel data articles and pooled time series articles. However there is no fixed terminology and although the situation is much better than in fixed/random effects terminology mess, there is some abuse of the terms.

Comment: @mpiktas  Good point about the terminology "mess." It is endemic to the literature in many, many areas. That said, I don't see how interchangeable use of the two terms at issue here constitutes "abuse."

Comment: @RichardHardy  Thank you for these suggestions. What would be great would be a reference or two concerning them in the context of panel data or pooled time series models.

Comment: @DJohnson, I certainly do not have any reference. I just applied a generally popular idea to this specific context.

Comment: @RichardHardy  Ay! And there's the rub.

Comment: The Baltagi's book "Econometric analysis of panel data" has a chapter on testing hypothesis for poolability of data. However you need to beware of certain issues. For panel data you may not be able to estimate the unrestricted model. For example if you have short time series, the unrestricted model will involve estimating individual regressions, and you will run into degrees of freedom issues. If you have enough data you will probably rely on T asymptotics, but your restricted model will be estimated with fixed T and large-N asymptotics, making the comparison statistically invalid.

Comment: You can chose to not use asymptotic results, then you need to assume that your disturbances are iid and normal, which means that all the Box-Jenkins issues are moot.

Comment: We have this mess, because it depends a lot on assumptions how data is generated. Different assumptions lead to using different mathematical tools, which are basically incompatible, i.e. if you use iid asumption on non-stationary data the inferences are invalid. The data sampling assumptions are hardest to test, because all the tests involve assumptions. So the assumptions are usually argued using the arguments specific with the domain of application. So more often and not it may seem that certain issues are not addressed, but they are in fact already addressed, i.e. ...

Comment: ... the statistical methodology is chosen beforehand. So if fixed-T large-N assymptotics is the golden standard in the specific domain, this excludes any discussion of Box-Jenkins issues, because their existence is ruled out beforehand. If you have suspicions that this is not correct, you need to revisit the discussion of how data is collected and what assumptions are made. If the standard arguments do not apply, then either you find literature which aligns to your specific case, or you have a researcher's problem, i.e. you need to devise new methods for treating your data.

Comment: @mpiktas  Excellent points. Thank you. This gives me more direction than I had before asking this question. Wrt your last sentence, see my comment below where I discuss the challenges of modeling some data I'm working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assertions about Wooldridge's book are not entirely correct.

1. Practically each estimation method Wooldridge discusses includes a section on robust inference, i.e. how to use covariance matrices which are robust to serial correlation or heteroscedasticity, i.e. HAC type covariance matrices. R package *plm* implements certain variants of such matrices proposed by Wooldridge.
2. Wooldridge touches on a subject of unit-roots, but only to state that his book is about classical *panel data*, i.e. where time series are short. All the results in the book are derived using N asymptotics, with T fixed, i.e. when the number of time series is going to infinity and their length stays the same. In that case all the time series issues are treated by different covariance structure of the regression disturbances.

Even now there is no agreed way of how to estimate panel models when the time series are long enough to warrant the the treatment of all the time series issues you have mentioned. If you look for unit-root or cointegration tests for panel data in the literature you will not find one simple test. Usually each author presents several variants, with varying assumptions. The DGPs of different authors usually are incompatible, and so on and so forth. So it is not easy to write a book an such subject, because there is no scientific consensus yet, how to treat such type of problems.

One of the possible reasons for this is that there are no compelling real life examples which would require both time-series and panel data treatment. If you have the data with sufficiently long time series, it is usually much easier just to treat each series separately and it is harder to justify the necessity of pooling the time series. There are several examples where such treatment is feasible, such in gravity models of trade, testing PPP hypotheses, but these are topics of specialized economic fields and the results are not easily generalized to general case.

Comment: Thank you for your closely read and well-informed comments. I agree that Wooldridge discusses robust inference, e.g., on p.152 of the 1st ed., "It is important to know what this robustness allows...in panel data models, an unrestricted (unconditional variance matrix) allows for *arbitrary* serial correlation and time-varying variances in the disturbances..." To me, this leaves a lot to the imagination. You also state that Wooldridge discusses unit roots but is there a citation for this?

Comment: Also, you mention literature addressing "unit-roots and cointegration tests for panel data." Do you have any references? As for "no compelling real life examples," I  can't agree with this, unless you are limiting your comment to econometric models. For instance, in marketing science, there are plenty of examples of situations with many *long* panels of this type, see, e.g., Lee Cooper's book *Market Share Analysis* available as a free download here... http://www.anderson.ucla.edu/faculty/lee.cooper/MCI_Book/BOOKI2010.pdf

Comment: @DJohnson, I guess *long panels* rather than *large panels* is what is relevant here.

Comment: @RichardHardy  Edited to reflect your observation.

Comment: Wooldridge discusses time series persistence (i.e. unit roots) in page 175, section 7.8.3. The exact quote: `... it may appear that we have not been careful in stating our assumptions. However, we do not need to restrict the dynamic behavior of our data in any way because we are doing fixed-T, large-N asymptotics.`  There is more in that section together with citations of relevant literature, i.e. works of Pesaran and Smith, and Phillips and Moon. Also Baltagi's book on panel data econometrics has a whole chapter devoted to time series issues.

Comment: @DJohnson I took a glance at the link but I failed to see the examples of long panels. From what I've seen the book employs the same fixed-T, large-N asymptotics, as evidenced by using of time dummies. If hold T fixed, then there is no point of thinking of time series issues, as they all assume T going to infinity. I could say more with the specific examples.

Comment: @mpiktas  See the section on panel data in the appendix...Cooper was writing in the late 80s and discusses the changes the introduction of scanner panel data were making on the kinds of models marketing scientists could develop.

Comment: @mpiktas  Thanks for the references. The fixed-T, large-N asymptotics is interesting to me as I'm working through an applied example involving massive N and unbalanced T's with T ranging from a few to over a thousand daily observations for a few N...a completely different challenge.

Comment: @DJohnson much of what I've said applies to balanced panels. For unbalanced panels the main issue is to determine why data is missing. Wooldridge demonstrates how this problem can be treated in section 17.7.1, page 578. Basically he states what assumptions are needed to reduce the problem to fixed-T large-N asymptotics. See whether they apply in your case. I suggest staying away from large-N, large-T asymptotics since the mathematical apparatus is quite complicated (relatively) in that case and the literature is more scarce.

Comment: @mpiktas Thanks again. Unfortunately, in analytics as in life, one plays with the data one's dealt...so to speak. I described this data on CV with this question... http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201610/predictive-modeling-of-an-complex-panel-of-heavy-tailed-data  But it was too much for people, I guess, as it generated no responses. Btw, I've been able to answer the question about how to model the extreme valued nature of the dependent variable using robust quantile regression.